How do I create a restorable Clonezilla image from a rootfs directory?
I've built a Debian rootfs for an embedded Linux platform using debootstrap et al. My goal is to make this installable to my devices over the network.
I previously built my own solution using iPXE but I'm evaluating switching to Clonezilla. However, I am not cloning an existing drive; I want to make the restorable image from my rootfs directory, and populate the necessary metadata fields about the partitions for Clonezilla to recreate on restore.
What is the process for "manually" creating a Clonezilla restore image? E.g., should I create a disk image with mkfs && mount -o loop and then clone it? Is there some incantation of partclone that supports this?
(A process that doesn't require root and/or that works inside a Docker container would be preferred, since that's easier to deploy via CI.)
